# Regular Expressions on Notepad++ two words on the same line

Tags: regex, string, find, notepad++, matching

I am trying to use Regular Expressions in notepad++ to find two words that are on the same line of each other. For example I want to find this line by searching for broker and suspicious:

> If a securities broker believes that a client might be engaging in transactions to launder money, the broker is required to file a Suspicious Activity Report.

I tried using **broker.*suspicious** but this would highlight the first instant of broker, all the way to the first instance of the word suspicious.

Any ideas would be extremely helpful!

Comment: Just uncheck *`.` matches newline* in the search dialog.

Comment: That result meets your requirements as you described them.  Why shouldn't it start from the first `broker`?

Comment: Please select whichever answer works best, so this question doesn't show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Notepad++, there should be a checkbox that says something like "`.` matches newline". Uncheck that and `.` will no longer match newlines, so it'll fail if it can't find "suspicious" on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive this is what you're looking for, but you can do something like this:

`broker[^\r\n]+suspicious`

To find every instance of broker...suspicious that isn't separated by a newline.

Comment: No need to use the second caret symbol, negation is already enforced with the first one.

Comment: Well today I learned! It looks like if we do include the second carat it will include that in the exclusion.

Comment: order of words is important, e.g. line "suspicious broker" will not be matched.

Answer (score 1):

Use positive [look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

broker(?!.*broker).*suspicious